# Erro ao fazer POST contendo "@" ou "#" em PHP com cURL

Tags: php, post, libcurl

Estou tendo um problema e não consigo corrigir, possuo um script em PHP que submete um formulário utilizando cURL.

Inicialmente eu utilizava o formato `array(key => value)` para submeter os dados do POST.

No entanto me surgiu um problema:

> Quando o @ está no ínicio do valor do campo, o cURL considera que estou realizando o upload de um arquivo.

Para corrigir este problema eu alterei o formato que monto o POST para uma string com formato GET `param=@valor`.

> No entanto quando o valor possui # (em qualquer parte) ele funciona como um delimitador (igual em links)

Nesse caso o `lor` será perdido.

```
param=va#lor
```

Bem, eu poderia corrigir isso fazendo um `if/else` e quando o valor possuir **#** eu utilizaria o formato `array`, porém se por um acaso o valor for `@ala#1010` ele irá falhar em ambos os casos.

Alguém consegue ver uma luz para esse problema?
Obs.: Quem recebe o POST é um servidor externo, então não posso mandar com URLEncode, pois lá não será tratado.

**Amostra de código que realiza o cURL:**

```
function exec_curl($ch, $url, $username, $post = null) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies/{$username}.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__). "/cookies/{$username}.txt");

        return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Comment: Não da para "skipar" com \?

Comment: Você precisa encodar corretamente o valor. Se fosse um `<form>` comum sendo postado, o browser já faria isso automaticamente.

Comment: Não @Guerra, se houver uma solução eu acredito que será pelo formato `array(key => value)`, onde eu consiga utilizar **@** como primeiro char e ele não considere que é um upload. Talvez uma forma de desabilitar isso no cURL.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ai que está, olhando pelo submit do form utilizando o console de desenvolvedor do chrome, o dado vai sem encode algum mesmo. Como eu disse, pelo formato `array` funciona perfeitamente, desde que não inicie com **@**, que é quando o cURL considera que estou realizando um upload de arquivo.

Comment: Acredito que a solução seria encodar mesmo, teria que debugar para ver se o server aceita algum tipo de encode. Se não aceitar acredito que não seja possivel.

Comment: Luis, o console do Chrome está te enganando, ele faz o decode antes de mostrar.

Comment: @bfavaretto De fato estava, peguei a string encodada e joguei estática no PHP e funcionou. Mas não entendi o motivo de não funcionar com o urlencode (eu havia testado), vou olhar se ele mudou algo a mais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que a solução seja usar ou o [`curl_escape`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-escape.php) caso use php 5.5 ou superior.
Ou o [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) que é similar e é o mesmo tratamento nativo do browser. Não custa testar e ver se o server aceita, se não aceitar o server está muito mal feito.

Comment: Realmente `urlencode` funcionou, eu já havia testado, no entanto eu tinha utilizado ele sobre toda a string dos parâmetros, assim ele encodava os **=** também, fiz o encode para cada parâmetro e funcionou.